# Timed out during setup when using Selenium Webdriver and TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running my testcases using Selenium and TestNG.

I am getting failed to invoke configuration method:
`com.tradeportal.init.SeleniumInit.setUp:Timed out waiting for page load`.

I am creating new session for my ff on `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`.is the error is due to this?

Comment: What's the entire stack trace? What code are you using to create the new session? What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox?